# How to dynamically check if input is empty without using onChange?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to get one-time information from the `input` control when value is empty and when value is not empty

Right now I'm using `onChange` like below:

```
<Input onChange={onChangeValue()} />
```

But this `onChangeValue` method is running every time when I type into the input, but I want two times information, first when value from input is empty and second when value from input is not empty.

Can someoone tell me what can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can put some logic before your `onChangeValue()` function that checks the input value's length and then calls `onChangeValue()`:

```js
beforeOnChangeValue = function() {
  if(arguments[0].target.value.length <= 1) return onChangeValue(arguments)
}
```

```html
<Input onChange={beforeOnChangeValue} />
```

This way the `onChangeValue()` function will only be called when the input is either emptied or when the first character is put in

Answer (score -1):

it seems like you're using controlled components (changing the value of the control on every key typing). I think based on your strategy that you could use a flag in the onChange handler like this

```js
  function onChange (evt) {
    setIsEmpty(!!evt.target.value);
    // Your code ...
  }
```

Then you'll always know if the input is empty or not.

```js
   function Form () {
     const [isEmpty, setIsEmpty] = React.useState(false);
     
      // onChange here

      return <Input className={isEmpty ? 'empty-class' : 'non-empty-class'} />
   }
```

Comment: I think that you don't understand the question in main post

Comment: I do, however, I don't get why you can't check the status on each `onChange`. You're already running a re-render on every key press